# how to make one background with two color?

Tags: css, reactjs

How can I write one CSS class to make the background almost all white? I want to make it so that bottom part is black with an arrow icon.

```
.search-rect {
        width: 160px;                   
        height: 200px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        padding-left: 3px;
        padding-right: 3px;
        background-color: #fafafa;
        border: 1px solid #424242;
        border-radius: 10px;        
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 10px;

        p {
            line-height: 150%;
        }
}
```

[image: The image]

Comment: use liner gradient. See example - `background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, transparent), color-stop(100%, $black));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements.
Like this: https://codepen.io/bsalex/pen/WXLpPY

Answer (score 0):

Try css gradients.
The syntax is :

```
background: linear-gradient(direction, color-stop1, color-stop2, ...);
```

For example,

```
#grad {
background: blue; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, yellow); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(red, yellow); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, yellow); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(red, yellow); /* Standard syntax */}
```